# obtener url de una imagen destacada wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Necesito obtener la url de la imagen destacada asignada a cada página.
Por ejemplo, en el siguiente caso, tengo el template shop y he obtenido su ID mediante:

```
$shop = get_option( 'woocommerce_shop_page_id' );
```

Aquí tengo una imagen destacada:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como no encuentro la manera de obtenerla con el id del template, he probado a meter directamente el id de esta imagen (poniendo el cursor encima sale en el enlace) con la función:

```
echo wp_get_attachment_image_src( 200, 'full' ); //200 es el ID
```

Esto tampoco me devuelve nada.
La razón por la que necesito la url es porque debo utilizarla como background-image, por lo que la imagen entera no me vale, debe ser solo la URL.

Gracias por adelantado.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar la función `get_the_post_thumbnail_url` que obtiene la url de la imagen destacada, sin necesidad de pasar un ID como parámetro, o bien con el id usando la función `get_post_thumbnail_id` y `wp_get_attachment_image_src`.

```
<?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'full' ); ?> 

<img src="<?php echo $image['0'] ?>">
```

Función the_post_thumbnail_url

```
<img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url( 'thumbnail' ); ?>">

<img src="<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>">
```

**Actualizacion**¨

Al ser shop una pagina recopilatoria obtiene datos del loop de productos, por ende no muestra el contenido del témplate, esto se soluciona creando un segundo loop usando `query_posts();` pasando el ID de la página como parámetro, por ejemplo:

```
<?php query_posts("page_id=IDPAGE"); while ( have_posts() ) : the_post() ?>

    <img src="<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>">

<?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Al final usamos `wp_reset_query();` para finalizar correctamente la función y que no afecte a otro loop

Comment: Gracias por la pronta respuesta. Ya he probado esas funciones también. El problema que estoy teniendo con ellas es que no me devuelven la imagen que tengo destacada en el template de SHOP, sino la imagen destacada del primer producto de la lista de productos en venta... Por eso necesito que tenga en cuenta el ID  del template que contiene la imagen...

Comment: @InfiniteRoads Asumo que la página shop es una pagina que obtiene un loop de productos no? entonces te muestra la imagen del primer producto, puedes crear un segundo while usando query_posts(), revisa mi respuesta de nuevo.

Comment: Gracias amigo. Finalmente lo conseguí de la siguiente manera: publico respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Primero compruebo si estoy en el template de la tienda:

```
if( is_shop() ) {
```

//obtengo su id mediante get_option, una función que recupera los ids de cada template y cuyos argumentos se encuentran en la tabla de la BBDD de wp_options

```
$shop_page_id = get_option('woocommerce_shop_page_id');
$thumbID = get_post_thumbnail_id( $shop_page_id );
$imgDestacada = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $thumbID, 'full' );
$pathImgDestacada = $imgDestacada[0];
echo $pathImgDestacada;
}
```